# What is wrong with my JavaScript assignment

Tags: javascript

I am practicing the **rock-paper-scissors assignment.** 
When I call playRound function manually it returns normal **(e.g tie true false tie tie).**
But when I call playRound function with iteration through game function it returns **(true true true true) or (false false false false false) or (tie tie tie tie tie)**, instead of something like **(false tie false true tie).** I used the if-else clause and now I used switch yet still the same output. please how will I solve the issue?

```
function getComputerPlay() {
    let selectAny = ["paper", "rock", "scissors"];
    let randomReturn = Math.floor(Math.random() * selectAny.length);
    return selectAny[randomReturn];
}

function getUserSelect(choice) {
    let userSelect = choice.toLowerCase();
    if (userSelect === "rock" || userSelect === "paper" || userSelect === "scissors") return userSelect;
    return "Not valid";
}

function playRound(playSelection, computerSelection) {
    if (playSelection === computerSelection) return "Tie!.";

    if (playSelection === "paper") {
        if (computerSelection === "rock") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (playSelection === "rock") {
        if (computerSelection === "scissors") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (playSelection === "scissors") {
        if (computerSelection === "rock")
            return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
function game(playSelection, computerSelection) {
    let win = 0;
    let lost = 0;
    let tie = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let playRoundReturn = playRound(playSelection, computerSelection);
        switch (playRoundReturn) {
            case true:
                win++;
                break;
            case false:
                lost++;
                break;
            default:
                tie++;
                break;
        }
    }
    console.log(win, lost, tie);

    return "You won " + win + "times, lost " + lost + "times and draw " + tie + "time";
}


let playSelection = getUserSelect("rock");
let computerSelection = getComputerPlay();
let play = game(playSelection, computerSelection);   //called playRound with iteration through game()
//let pl = playRound(playSelection, computerSelection);  //called playRound manually
console.log(play);
```

Comment: You only generate a random number for the computer selection once

Comment: I don't get your response well. Please look at the for loop in the game(). For every i the playRound will be called.

Comment: Thanks man. i understood what you mean now. i got it

Answer (score -1):

This is because the `playSelection` is always 'rock', and the `computerSelection` only runs the random gen once, so will always be the same value for all 5 rounds.

Move the random generator into the for loop, e.g.

`let playRoundReturn = playRound(playSelection, getComputerPlay());`

Comment: Waoo.. thanks @amcquaid. I got it now. I appreciate.